# Remove the strong tag from a html string

Tags: java

I have s string containg a html text. I want to remove the strong tag from it and keep the text inside the tag.
For this input:

```
some text <strong> example </strong other text
```

the result should be:

```
some text example other text
```

I tried this but this is deleting the text inside the strong tag

```
String target = htmlString.replaceAll("<strong.*</strong>", "");
```

Comment: Is it `java` or `javascript`? Sounds more like java, to me. Besides, the input provided has `</strong` instead of `</strong>`. Is it intended?

Comment: "some text <strong> example </strong other text".replace('<strong>','').replace('</strong','')

Answer (score 3):

```
htmlString.replace(/<strong>|<\/strong>/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Stack_Ex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "some text <strong> example </strong other text";


    text = text.replaceFirst(" <strong>","");
    text = text.replaceFirst(" </strong","");


    System.out.println(text);

}}
```

**Output:** some text example other text